# Git: manifest missing or unreadable

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm trying to repo a link. **These are some of the commands I want to execute:**

```
repo init \-u ssh://website.com:29418/repo
repo sync
```

**I get the following error when I do it.**

```
M-70NN:bin rda$ repo init \-u ssh://website.com:29418/repo
error: in `init -u ssh://website.com:29418/cmx-ng-repo`: 

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/rda/bin/.repo/manifests/.git/HEAD'
error: manifest missing or unreadable -- please run init
```

**I don't know what to do. I have followed the above guide to install repo and other stuff:**

```
http://threadeds.blogspot.com/2009/02/getting-started-with-google-android-on.html
```

**I have even tried**

> repo init

But i get the same error. I'm quite new to GIT. Not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to run repo init with a .git directory already inside your project. Here's someone with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091404/repo-about-git-head-error-manifest-missing-or-unreadable-please-run-init (maybe?)

Comment: Let me know if you need further help ;)

Answer (score 0):

***Solution :***

Try the following command

```
repo init -u ssh://user@website.com:29418/repo
repo sync
```

The default.xml should be present on the repo link

instead of

```
repo init \-u ssh://website.com:29418/repo
repo sync
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the backslash in front of `-u` being wrong if you're issuing the command as a single line, the error might be caused by having a hidden `.repo` directory already in one of the parent directories. I.e. you cannot have nested repo trees.