# repo about .git/HEAD: error: manifest missing or unreadable -- please run init

Tags: android, git

I was downloading android 4.4 source code using repo(in ubuntu). Last time I killed repo process by pressing the key combination: Ctrl+Z, and when I started it this time by using the command: "repo init" and "repo sync", I got the following errors:

> error: in `sync`: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   u'/home/ubuntu/workspace/packages/apps/VoiceDialer/.git/HEAD' error:
>   manifest missing or unreadable -- please run init

I've tried "run init", which displays no errors. But the problem remains after running "repo init". What should I do? Is there any way to tell repo to reproduce the ./git/HEAD file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the VoiceDialer folder, then running "repo init" and "repo sync". With the .git folder in it, it may not "repo init" successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I also get the problem. Here are the steps:
1. delete the folder
2. 'repo sync' the folder again.

Answer (score 0):

Error is usually solved by starting your repo init from scratch.  This includes deleting the folder it is downloading to.  You will need to remake the directory that you deleted with

mkdir -p ~/mydirectory

at which point you will be ready to reinitialize the repo download from scratch.

If you are initializing a master repo for a build you will need to start from scratch, otherwise you will keep getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers involved deleting the whole directory. While this works, it seems like an overkill. The same result can be achieved by deleting the .repo dir that was created when running repo init at the location it was ran in.

That prevents re-downloading the whole remote repo again.

Note: If there is no such dir at the current location, it may be in one of the parent directories.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going to /usr/bin/repo and changing the manifest pointer from 'manifest' to 'manifest.git'

Using an older version of git, 2.14 that's 3rd party for Centos 6.6